# Swift - searching through dictionaries in an array in a plist

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, plist

I'm making a simple app that searches through a large plist that contains geographical fixes, with corresponding lat and long coordinates. The plan is to be able to search for these fixes in a search box, and then push a button to position a mapview with the fix in the center, and a pin at the exact coordinates.

I have the interface setup, the map working and just need to enable the button to search for the fix that the user inputs, return the lat long, and forward these to the map. I've been looking through answers on here for hours now and tried versions of what I found with no luck..

This is the plist:

[image]

It is quite a lot of fixes as you can see... What would be the best way to go about this? I'm at a loss how to go on from here.

This is what I'm using to position the map

```
func zoomToRegion() {
  let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 62, longitude: 16)
  let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 700000.0, 900000.0)

  mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
}
```

As you see right now I have just manually entered a lat and long but it works anyway.

The closest I came to making it work was following this guide: http://rshankar.com/how-to-add-mapview-annotation-and-draw-polyline-in-swift/ However I don't want the fixes to be on the map until someone searches for them, and I was unable to convert that code to do what I wanted..

Thanks for any help or insight into this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd rather store them lat & long as Double, but anyway, you should create an NSArray first from that .plist
([Read from .plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31688761/swift-2-ios-9-plist-reading-and-writing))
Then filter that array, whether it stores the same lat & long values that the user typed in.

```
guard let filePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("YOUR_FILE_NAME", ofType: "plist"),    
let locationsArray = NSArray(contentsOfFile:filePath) else {
    print("Couldn't load .plist as an array")
    return
}

// TODO: Replace them with the actual user input
let userInputText: String = "ALABA"

// It may not contain any items
let filteredLocations = locationsArray.filter { (element) -> Bool in
    guard let title = element["title"] as? String where
      userInputText == title else { return false }
    return true
}

// To convert String lat & long to Double
let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.decimalSeparator = ","

// If you only need the first result:
guard let locationDict = filteredLocations.first as? [String:AnyObject],
    let latString = location["lat"] as? String, 
    let longString = location["long"] as? String,
    let latitude = numberFormatter.numberFromString(latString)?.doubleValue,
    let longitude = numberFormatter.numberFromString(longString)?.doubleValue else {
       print("No result"); return
    }

// Your location
let location = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: latitude, 
    longitude: longitude
)

// Do something with your location
let region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(location, 700000.0, 900000.0)
mapView.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```

But it'd be nicer if you implemented a class, something like LocationData, with the properties given in the .plist, and you'd crate a [LocationData] array, so you could reach the lat & long by properties of an object, not by key from a dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! One thing I might not have been clear enough about, what I want to search for is the fix or "title" itself. As in the picture of the plist, I want to search for ABALA and get the lat and long for that title.

Comment: I updated the code & hope that's what you're looking for.

Comment: I would love to convert the lat/long to double instead of string. Dont know how to do that with 466*2 strings in a plist though. Problem is I am quite inexperienced still, but learning. This simple app would help me greatly however so I kinda wanted to get it to work, then I have lots of time for learning more before I attempt to go further.

Unfortunately your suggested code is not working for me, probably because I don't understand enough to implement it correctly.. I tried making a function of it with no luck. "Use of local variable location before its declaration".

Comment: Updated code contains String to Double conversation, according to your .plist content. 
If you get an error like this, you probably didn't assign any value to your "location" variable before you try to reach it's value. You may assign a value to it in an "if" block, but you don't assign anything to it in the "else" block.

Comment: That did it! I just changed the location variable to locationDict and now it works, thanks a ton.