# Trouble on plist file using swift

Tags: ios, swift, plist

I have two variable called "Countries" and "Places" and I'm trying to read a Data.plist and retrieve some values

This is the Data.plist:

[Data.plist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGEcR.png)

I can't read the plist from the variables.

Let use as an example, the value of Countries is "Italia" and the value of Places is "Naples", how can I retrieve the two different values written in "Item 0" and "Item 1".

I've been searching for days in internet some tutorial who could help me but I couldn't make any of these working for my case (I used more tutorial examples but due my low reputation I can't post more than 2 links).

I tried to follow these tutorial:

[Swift - searching through dictionaries in an array in a plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34122246/swift-searching-through-dictionaries-in-an-array-in-a-plist)

http://sweettutos.com/2015/06/03/swift-how-to-read-and-write-into-plist-files/

I tried, for example, to use this code without use the "variables", but even this is not working:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Dati", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
let value: AnyObject = (dict!.objectForKey("Italia")!.objectForKey("Naples")?.objectForKey("Item 0"))!
```

Can you please help me on this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `I can't read the plist from the variables.` Please show your current attempt in your question (you can use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34639545/edit) button).

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: That tutorial is for arrays. Looks like your plist root it is a dictionary

Comment: Also you are not being consistent. Some of your array items are Numbers, some are Strings

Comment: `Item 0` represents the first item of an array so it's rather `objectAtIndex(0)`

Answer (score 0):

This is a pure Swift solution using only Swift native types:

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Dati", withExtension: "plist"), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
  do {
    let dictionary = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:AnyObject]
    if let city = dictionary["Italia"]?["Naples"] as? [AnyObject] {
      let item0 = city[0] as! Int
      let item1 = city[1] as! String
    } else {
      print("Italia or Naples doesn't exist")
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Property List Serialization Error: \(error)")
  }
} else {
  fatalError("File couldn't be read")
}
```

If you change the plist file to use only `String` values you can avoid some type casting

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("Dati", withExtension: "plist"), data = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) {
  do {
    let dictionary = try NSPropertyListSerialization.propertyListWithData(data, options: [], format: nil) as! [String:[String:[String]]]
    if let city = dictionary["Italia"]?["Naples"] {
      let item0 = city[0]
      let item1 = city[1]
    } else {
      print("Italia or Naples doesn't exist")
    }
  } catch let error as NSError {
    print("Property List Serialization Error: \(error)")
  }
} else {
  fatalError("File couldn't be read")
}
```

Comment: much easier to just cast as [String:[String:[String]]] dictionary containing dictionaries of array of strings. Don't forget to mention that his file some items are numbers and some are strings. He needs to fix it

Comment: I admit it's a bit exaggerated, but there are some `Int`'s in the plist

Comment: doesn't look like he needs two different types there

Comment: Indeed, that would make things a lot easier, I updated the answer

Comment: @vadian: Thanks a lot. This is exactly what a was looking for. :) I can't accept the answer due my reputation but I accept 200% your answer!